# ggplot geom_col plot scaling (unreadable)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a table, but due to the number of persons and the length of the texts the table is no longer readable at all, how do I get it to be more friendly to read.

```
df %>% 
group_by(Rayonmanager, Contract) %>%
    summarise(Aantal=n()) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Rayonmanager, Aantal), y = Aantal))+
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = Aantal), hjust = 2)+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none") + 
  facet_wrap(~ Contract)
```

[image]

Comment: I would consider the following options. 1. Reduce data, 2. change chart type, 3. use nudge option, 4. group data and use facet, 5. increase y scale limit

Comment: 6. Use facet_wrap_paginate to run more than a page